# Call value on array without index

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Call value on array without index

Array

```
$Extension = ['jpeg','jpg','png'];
```

View

```
<img src="{{ $dirname }}{{ $id }}-daftarpengalaman.{{$Extension}}" class="img-responsive" style="display: block; margin: auto; width:50%" alt="Daftar Pengalaman"/>
```

please help me

Comment: what've you tried?

Comment: check again....

Comment: can you give a solution

Comment: what does "call value on array without index" mean? what are you trying to do?

Comment: what extension you want call here ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want call **jpeg**

```
<img src="{{ $dirname }}{{ $id }}-daftarpengalaman.{{$Extension[0]}}" />
```

if you want call **jpg**

```
<img src="{{ $dirname }}{{ $id }}-daftarpengalaman.{{$Extension[1]}}" />
```

if you want call **png**

```
<img src="{{ $dirname }}{{ $id }}-daftarpengalaman.{{$Extension[2]}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want to do But As I understand you want to print the array value without giving their indexing. So according to me it's not possible to show array value without Index.
You can print it but then you have to user for-each loop for this like below

```
$Extension = ['jpeg','jpg','png'];

foreach($Extension as $ex){
 echo $ex.'<br>';
}
```

OutPut: **jpeg
        jpg
        png**